# in shell script,how to compare two csv files?

Tags: scripting

i have two csv files which are having three fields(length,width,height). length and width values are same in two files.for some cases, height value differs between these files.
i want to find out  these values(length,width,height) when these two files get difference.

How to do this.

Comment: Please provide more context such as the OS, the scripting program you are using/considering, and possibly some code stub of what you've come up with until now.

Answer (score 0):

I would use python and the csv module:
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that both files have the same number of lines, you can use diff command:

```
o:/tmp$ cat t1.csv
10,11,12
10,21,12
10,23,23
10,25,22
9,23,45
5,04,3
5,6,5

o:/tmp$ cat t2.csv 
10,11,12
10,21,12
10,23,25
10,25,20
9,23,45
5,04,3
5,6,5


o:/tmp$ diff t1.csv t2.csv 
3,4c3,4
< 10,23,23
< 10,25,22
---
> 10,23,25
> 10,25,20
```

And this tells you immediately the different lines.